# How to disable day selection in Datepicker dialog

Tags: android, datepicker, android-datepicker

I want to disable the day selection in date picker dialog. I used the below line to disable but i am getting crash (Null pointer Exception). Please help me to fix this issue

```
((ViewGroup) datePickerDialog.getDatePicker()).findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day", "id", "android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Full code :

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                        tvDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
        ((ViewGroup) datePickerDialog.getDatePicker()).findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("day", "id", "android")).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        datePickerDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DD/MM/YYYY

```
 LinearLayout pickerParentLayout = (LinearLayout) datePicker.getChildAt(0);
 LinearLayout pickerSpinnersHolder = (LinearLayout) pickerParentLayout.getChildAt(0);
 NumberPicker picker = (NumberPicker) pickerSpinnersHolder.getChildAt(0);
 picker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

NumberPicker picker = (NumberPicker) pickerSpinnersHolder.getChildAt(0);
 change this line what you want to hide.